# How to run binary/exe that's part of a Java Web Application deployed on HEROKU?

Tags: java, jsp, heroku, chmod, permission-denied

I have a Dynamic Web Project, developed with Eclipse, converted in a Maven project.

I have exported the WAR, and i have deployed it on HEROKU.

The issue is :

```
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/app/target/tomcat.21601/webapps/expanded/lib/binary": error=13, Permission denied
```

This binary is called by the servlet for doing some stuffs, but maybe it needs chmod command.

From the Heroku console, I can't find a way to reach the binary and run chmod, cause the WAR is not a directory.

How I can chmod a binary that is part of Web application, on the Heroku machine?